# Use JMeter to simulate multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: jmeter

Hi I am new to JMeter.

- Is it possible that I can input a CSV file (with 25 rows of unique customerID number) and use **many HTTP (GET) URL request simultaneously for every row in the csv** file?

Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have one thread group, with n threads, what you describe is the default behavior of `CSV data set` when you set the `sharing mode` to `All threads`. Every thread, will pickup the customer id from next line of the file.

Please see following link for details.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run the threads simultaneously? Because at present they are running sequentially.

Comment: In your threadgroup configuration,  you will have to set the no. of users to more than 1.

Comment: I have 3 thread, where 2nd and 3rd thread should run after 1st. 1st thread I need it to run only once. The 2nd and 3rd I want to run simultaneously. When I increase the thread users to >1, they are still running sequentially?

Comment: I think you are getting confused between sampler and thread. Can you post your test plan.